# Make Ajax Post when val on input changes and checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, post

I have 3 input fields:

```
Title: <input type="text" value="Testa Ieraksts" id="blog_title"><br>
Check: <input type="checkbox" value="" id="blog_url_change"><br>
URL:   <input type="text" value="" id="blog_slug" disabled="disabled"><br>
```

**GOAL:** When Checkbox is checked input#blog_slug is set to non-disabled, and then i want on input#blog_title changes send ajax post with var DATA.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

$('input#blog_url_change').click(function(){
        $('input#blog_slug').attr('disabled', !$(this).attr('checked'));

        var STATUS = $('input#blog_url_change').prop('checked');

        if (STATUS === true) {

        $('input#blog_title').on('change', function() {

                    var DOMAIN  = window.location.hostname;
                    var DATA    = this.value;

                                $.ajax({
                                    type: 'POST',
                                    url:  "http://" +  DOMAIN + "/blog/helper/geturl",
                                    data: 'data=' + DATA,
                                    dataType: 'json',
                                    success:    function (response) {
                                        console.log(response.url);
                                        $('input#blog_slug').val(response.url);
                                    }, 
                                }); // End Ajax  
                });
       }
   });
});
```

**Problem**: I need post only when checkbox is checked and title input val changes.
How to link these mothods together?

Comment: Why don't you listen to an `onchange` event on `$('#blog_title')`, and check if checkbox is checked inside it?

Comment: Thank you, solved! A little bit of changing the logical structure :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks For @iCore ;)

```
  $('input#blog_title').on('change', function() {
        $('input#blog_url_change').click(function(){
        $('input#blog_slug').attr('disabled', !$(this).attr('checked'));
                var STATUS = $('input#blog_url_change').prop('checked');
                console.log(STATUS);
                if (STATUS === true) {
                    var DOMAIN  = window.location.hostname;
                    var DATA    = $('input#blog_title').val();
                                $.ajax({
                                    type: 'POST',
                                    url:  "http://" +  DOMAIN + "/blog/helper/geturl",
                                    data: 'data=' + DATA,
                                    dataType: 'json',
                                    success:    function (response) {
                                        console.log(response.url);
                                        $('input#blog_slug').val(response.url);
                                    }, 
                                }); // End Ajax  
                }// End If
             });
    });
```